# Change Font and Color in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm new at Jade and I'm just wondering how do I change font and color of the texts? If I have a layout.jade that I'm using to extend to my helloworld.jade and userlist.jade; and I only want to change the font and color of userlist.jade. I'm just wondering what the syntax would be. Is it something like

```
extends layout

style
    h1{font-size: 19px; color: #464646;}
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

However I'm getting errors like

```
"Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both"
```

Also I'm using node.js to run my server. 
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a trailing dot after `style` in order to make the jade parser ignore anything indented under the style tag. In your example it's trying to read the `h1` as a tag nested within the `style` tag, rather than just plain text to be interpreted as CSS rules by the browser.

```
extends layout

style.
    h1 {
        font-size: 19px;
        color: #464646;
    }
block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
```

[Working example.](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/trLAD)

Remove the dot after `style` in that codepen and you'll see that their jade parser yells at you and says it can't interpret the `h1` tag you're trying to nest within the `style` tag.

PS - You also had differing indentation sizes. Your indentation needs to be either all tabs, or all spaces (same number of spaces). Jade doesn't let you mix and match indentation styles since it depends on your indentation to compile the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `style` element as a code block, or else it will parse it as HTML. And use consistent indentation.

```
extends layout

style.
  h1{font-size: 19px; color: #464646;}
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any errors anymore, however the font size and color are not changing. Any ideas on why it's not? Thanks

Comment: The docs seem to be lacking on what `block content` is. Perhaps the `style` needs to be within the block?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is a quick solution

```html
extends layout

h3(style=" color: #FF333") Your text here
h2(style=" color: #283FF") Your text here
```